# Create-react-app-parcel-typescript with Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, parceljs

I'm using create-react-app-parcel-typescript and want to use Jest. But I get the error:

● Validation Error:

Module C:...\polyfills.js in the setupFiles option was not found.

Configuration Documentation:
  https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html

error Command failed with exit code 1.

Does anyone know how to get it to work?

Comment: which commands did you use

Comment: have you added [src/setupTests.js](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests#src-setuptestsjs-1) file ?

Comment: I did "yarn test" No did not add any src/setupTests.js file.